# How to print sections of .txt file based on character

Tags: python, file, file-io, token

I'm writing a program that reads questions from a .txt file. Questions are surrounded by dashes "-----" The question is also followed by four possible correct answers and then followed by the answer. I have no clue how to separate each of these to print. The file is over 10,000 lines long and I need to be able to print a single question at a time but I'm not sure how to specify to only read in between the dashes.

TEXT EXAMPLE:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #1010 How tall is the actor Verne Troyer, famous for his role as Mini-me
        in the Austin Powers films?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *36 inches
 *32 inches
 *24 inches
 *35 inches

Answer: 32 inches

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #1011 Who auditioned for the role of James Bond in 1969 but was turned
        down for being too tall?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *John Cleese
 *Peter Snow
 *Simon Dee
 *Christopher Lee

Answer: Peter Snow
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide a [mcve] of your work and point out exactly where it's not working out?

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This splits it into blocks:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().split('-' * 5)
```

I'd need more specifics or an example to do more.

EDIT(with example):

```
qa_dict = dict()
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    spacer = '-' * 75
    last_q = ''
    #grab each block, one at a time, where a block is a q or a
    for block in f.read().split(spacer):
        #if block is a question
        if '#' in block and '?' in block:
            if last_q != '':  
                print('something went wrong around:', block)
            last_q = ' '.join(block.split())
        #if block is an answer
        elif last_q != '':
            #remove messy whitespace, throw choices and answer into an array
            choices_ans = list(filter(lambda let:len(let.strip()) > 0, block.split('\n')))
            #build a {question:(choices, answer)} dictionary
            qa_dict[last_q] = (choices_ans[:-1], choices_ans[-1])
            last_q = ''
        elif block.strip() != '':
            print('received answer without question', block)
#print out everything
for question in qa_dict.keys():
    choices, ans = qa_dict[question]
    print(question)
    print('\n'.join(choices))
    print(ans)
```

Comment: Thanks! So there's a lot of questions so I'm going to be using a random number generator and then use that number to find a specific question. I'll add an example of what it looks like.

Comment: Updated, is that what you were looking for?  There are many potential corner cases, but it's not worth solving those unless your data actually has them IMO.

Comment: Yes, it's working great! Do you know how I would go about printing the answer options beneath the question that's printed?

Comment: The if statement is capturing the questions, so if you want to do something with the other blocks (answers), you add an else block and it'll catch all the answers.  The exact code for answers will depend on how you want to format them.

Comment: I was trying to do that for a while but unlike with the questions where there's a number to look for, I can't search for a number for the questions. I've been trying to use readline() to get the next line with the answers but it's only printing a blank statement.

Comment: my read() statement earlier in the code reads the entire file in one go, so any readlines you do will return nothing.  You already have all the data in variables, so there's no need to access the file again.  If you add an else block to the existing if and do print(block), you'll see the raw answer data.

Comment: Hm I tried that earlier and print(block) was printing the entire file rather than just the answer data

Comment: I threw together the answer part with some comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to parse the contents of the file.

This code makes the following assumptions:

- You are using Python 3.6+ (f-strings) - the code can easily be modified to accomodate older versions
- The separator consists of 75 dashes
- The question text is prefixed with some whitespace, the `'#'`
  character and some digits, followed by a single whitespace
- The answers are separated by the `'*'` character
- The correct answer is prefixed with the string `"Answer: "`
- At least one newline separates the correct answer and the next
  question's separator.

If even a single question in your text file is not well defined and does not conform to this format, it will either not be captured by the regular expression, or raise an exception.

This code takes advantage of named capturing groups, but that's just for convenience. I've also elected to use `collections.namedtuple` to represent `Question` objects. We iterate through all regex matches to generate a list of `Question` objects:

```
def main():
    from collections import namedtuple
    import re as regex

    Question = namedtuple("Question", ["text", "answers", "correct_answer"])

    with open("questions.txt", "r") as file:
        content = file.read()

    sep = "-" * 75

    pattern = f"{sep}\\s+#\\d+\\s(?P<question>.+?(?={sep})){sep}\\s+(?P<answers>.+?(?=Answer: ))Answer: (?P<correct_answer>[^\\n]+)"

    questions = []

    for result in regex.finditer(pattern, content, flags=regex.DOTALL):
        question_text = " ".join(result.group("question").split())
        answers = list(filter(None, map(str.strip, result.group("answers").split("*"))))
        correct_answer = result.group("correct_answer").strip()

        questions.append(Question(question_text, answers, correct_answer))

    print(questions)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
[Question(text='How tall is the actor Verne Troyer, famous for his role as Mini-me in the Austin Powers films?', answers=['36 inches', '32 inches', '24 inches', '35 inches'], correct_answer='32 inches'), Question(text='Who auditioned for the role of James Bond in 1969 but was turned down for being too tall?', answers=['John Cleese', 'Peter Snow', 'Simon Dee', 'Christopher Lee'], correct_answer='Peter Snow')]
```

Once you have your question objects, it's trivial to set up the rest of the quiz. For example, picking a random question is as simple as `question = random.choice(questions)`. That being said, you're probably better off using `questions = random.sample(questions, k=10)` to pick your questions randomly (ten in this case). Using `random.choice` would allow for the same question to be picked more than once, though it would be pretty unlikely in a file with many questions.

Comment: This is great but unfortunately for my project, the only module we are allowed to import is random :(